# Alternative word/phrase for for company branding, logo, image, colour scheme used, etc

Tags: single-word-requests

What is an alternative word or phrase to describe a company's branding, logo, image, colour scheme used, etc.

*A while back I read this but cannot remember what it is.*

Comment: Is it the identity?

Comment: @Laurel it "included" identity too, as an umbrella term. It referred mainly towards company colours and logos, but included branding, etc as implicit

Comment: Standards manual or standards guide.

Comment: I think branding *is* the umbrella term; if not that, then *image.*

Answer (score 1):

This is the company's ***corporate identity.***

> the qualities of a company that make it different from other companies, and the images, words, etc. that it uses to make itself familiar to its customers, for example in its advertisements, on its letters, etc.:
>
> > As part of the process of developing our corporate identity we have recently introduced a new logo and new letterheads.
>
> — [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/corporate-identity)

> A corporate identity or corporate image is the manner in which a corporation, firm or business enterprise presents itself to the public (such as customers and investors as well as employees). The corporate identity is typically visualized by branding and with the use of trademarks, but it can also include things like product design, advertising, public relations etc. Corporate identity is a primary goal of the corporate communications, in order to maintain and build the identity to accord with and facilitate the corporate business objectives.
>
> In general, this amounts to a corporate title, logo (logotype and/or logogram) and supporting devices commonly assembled within a set of corporate guidelines. These guidelines govern how the identity is applied and usually include approved colour palettes, typefaces, page layouts, fonts, and others.
>
> — [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corporate_identity)